# How to get Deployment manager hostname and port dynamically in IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 using shell script in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, ibm, websphere

I need to get the deployment manager hostname and port dynamically in IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5 using shell script.

Comment: Where's the shell script running? Some federeated node?

Comment: yes. I running shell script in Depoyment Manager Profiles bin path and also i am in need to run desktop too...